# How to add exports to .zshrc

Tags: terminal, shell, zsh

I'm using a new Mac with a default shell of `zsh`. I've installed some certificates, but there are extra steps required:

```
Add the following to your .bashrc or .bash_profile or .zshrc:
export SOME_THING_1="/my/path/cert1.crt"
export SOME_THING_2="/my/path/cert2.crt"
export SOME_THING_3="/my/path/cert3.crt"
```

Note that `SOME_THING_X` above is not `PATH`.

Is it okay for me to manually edit the `.zshrc` file in notepad via `open ~/.zshrc` and paste in these lines? If so, where should I paste?

**`.zshrc:`**

```
export NVM_DIR="$HOME/.nvm"
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh"  # This loads nvm
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion"  # This loads nvm bash_completion
```

Or is this bad practice? Should I instead use something like `echo 'export SOME_THING_1="/my/path/cert1.crt"' >>~/.zshrc`? If so, should I keep the double quotes `""` around the file path to the right of the `=` sign or remove them?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just run `open ~/.zshrc` on the command line, which will open your `.zshrc` file in your default text editor (usually TextEdit) and, as long as you save it as plain text, you’ll be fine.

It doesn’t really matter where you paste it into your `.zshrc` file, as nothing else in there depends on it.

There’s no magic to `.zshrc`, other than that `zsh` will automatically execute it on startup; it’s just a text file. The only requirement is that it has valid Zsh code inside.

In general, I wouldn't recommend you `echo` or `print` straight to `.zshrc` (despite many examples and instructions doing so). It’s too easy to “accidentally the whole thing”.

Comment: That's why I asked! When I was echoing stuff, at one point I echo'd the same thing multiple times and thus accidentally created duplicates that seemed difficult to permanently remove. So I preferred to edit the file directly. Thanks!